# ASP.NET WebApi - How do I "allow", but not "require" client certificates?

Tags: c#, security, ssl, asp.net-web-api, client-certificates

In IIS, I can "ignore", "allow" and "require" client certificates.

In ASP.NET WebAPI (version 4.0 that just launched a little while back), I seem to have the ability to only "ignore" or "require".

By default, client certificates are ignored... so this statement always yields null:

```
var cert = actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();
```

But, if I set this flag on my config:

```
config.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```

Then I get the client cert... but, I no longer have the ability to allow anonymous access.

My anonymous client now gets a `403` error: "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Can I do a sort of "allow" like in IIS?

Comment: Have you tried using the identity model code covered here? http://leastprivilege.com/2012/08/20/support-for-x-509-client-certificates-in-thinktecture-identitymodel-for-web-api/... Perhaps this approach coupled with the use of the AllowAnonymous attribute may help? http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-allowanonymous-attribute-and-authorize-attribute may help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation with using X509 Certificate in self host scenario. The actual limitation is from the underlying transport binding in WCF, which does not have the *allow* option with regards to Client Certificate.

You can, however, allow multiple authentications schemes with other options, such as anonymous and windows. We are working with the WCF team to find out if we can add that support with anonymous and x509 certificate as well.

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the supplied certificate is invalid?
If that's the case, the following can help you:
[RemoteCertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback.aspx)

Comment: The 403 error didn't come from an invalid cert... it comes if anonymous... meaning, no cert at all.

Comment: Ah I misread that part. Does it throw the exception in code? Is there a inner exception?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The error with no cert is the same as with an invalid cert... basically, it looks like if you ask for a certificate, it makes it "required".